# Are there any Java-compilers that leverage an OSGi-environment instead of using the classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, osgi, javac

Are there any ways to make `javac` use an existing OSGi-environment for the resolution of build-time dependencies instead of setting the classpath explicitely? I know I could write an OSGi-component that uses the Compiler-API of the JDK, but I think there should be a more straightforward solution.

Alternatively, if no such extension is available for `javac`, does `ejc` allow such a thing (usable from the command line; I'd be willing to accept an Equinox-only solution with `ejc`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ant task to compile using osgi.

http://www.ohloh.net/p/osgijc

or here now I guess?

http://code.google.com/p/eclipseosgitools/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage dependencies?  There are plugins available for IDEs like Eclipse.  You just need to map the resource servers, and the needed libraries in a pom.xml, and that is pretty much it.

-Jay

Comment: Maven won't handle hiding packages that aren't imported; they implicitly make all packages available from a dependency rather than the required subset.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing out on the one obvious Java compiler that follows OSGi rules - Eclipse.

You can use Eclipse's compiler to do a headless build, but be warned, it's not for the faint-hearted.

Here's a simple [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html) on building with Eclipse and ant.

If you go down this path, I'd suggest looking at [Tycho](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Tycho+project+overview) (the Maven sub-project for building OSGi stuff) and [Buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/), an Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing in the [Lotus Expeditor Toolkit](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?q=Lotus+Expeditor+Toolkit) and Eclipse Plugin - It's a no-charge download. My build time and runtime classpaths are managed very easily by entries in the Manifests.

[disclaimer: I am an IBM employee.]